# angular 14 and node js websocket error ng cli was failed trying to reconnect

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io, angular2-routing

I am using the Angular 14 project front-end and Node.js as the server. I am getting these errors, but I didn't use websocket. I am trying to host the application on Apache 2 and getting these errors, but I am getting them continuously. This error caused my api call to delay response, and sometimes it took a long time to get data from the api. The API stage has been pending for a long time.